# Android - Swipe an Image without using ViewPager

Tags: android, image, view, android-viewpager

How to implement image swiping like ViewPager without using ViewPager? The same animations, gestures, but without the ViewPager

Comment: use viewflipper...http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/android-viewflipper-example.html

Comment: try this http://blog.sqisland.com/2012/07/android-swipe-image-viewer.html

Comment: @N.V.Rao, good, but i want to control moving with gesture like using ViewPager

Answer (score 1):

Use Viewflipper or you have do Animation .....but its better to use Viewpager.Try this 
[link](https://github.com/javatechig/Android-UI-Tutorials/tree/master/ViewFlipperExample)